# how to move music from iphone to mac?

Tags: macos, ios, music

I have an iphone with a lot of music. I would like to copy that music to my mac.  I do not understand how to do it.

Is there a tutorial that I can follow? I would prefer to do not install extra software. I have itunes already installled.

EDIT:

The automated way does not seem to work.  Here a screenshot

[image]

EDIT 2:

Apparently it is not possible to do it with itunes.  Is there a suggested 3rd party solution?.  I would also be happy of a solution using the terminal or some code.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83966/discussion-on-question-by-donbeo-how-to-move-music-from-iphone-to-mac).

Comment: you could use iexplorer.   https://macroplant.com